# read uploaded text file into text widget (django forms)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a file upload that takes a text file, and reads the input (contentOfFile).

The file upload, and reading of the data works fine (I've tested it), but I'm having issues trying to populate my text area widget with this data.

views.py

```
 uploaded1 = request.FILES['uploaded']
 contentOfFile = uploaded1.read()
 textInput1.innerHTML = contentOfFile
```

forms.py

```
class HomeForm(forms.Form):
    textInput1 = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',


        }

    ))

    class Meta:
        fields = {'textInput1',}
```

template.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.textInput1 }}
                <button type="submit" name="compare" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Compare</button>

            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Took a while but managed to figure this out.

The text widget is **form.textInput1** and **'uploaded1'** refers to the file input in templates. 
I had to add the for loop to prevent the text area from display '/b' before the uploaded text. I think this is to do with type conversion from binary, so the for loop converts this manually into a string

I hope this helps someone in the future.

views.py:

```
form = HomeForm(initial=dict(foo=request.FILES))
if 'uploaded1' in request.FILES:
    upload1 = request.FILES['uploaded1'].read()
    data1 = ""
    for x in upload1:
        data1 = data1 + chr(x)
    form.initial['textInput1'] = data1
    args = {'uploaded1': upload1, 'form': form, }
    if upload1:
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

template.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.textInput1 }}
                <input type="file" name="uploaded1" accept=".txt"/>
                <input type="submit" value="upload sample text"  class="btn btn-primary mb-2"/>
</form>
```